# Bad substitution in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have written this code in which m getting bad substitution error. Please help here.

```
#!/bin/bash

function detect_value(){

    #some operation gives u a value
    echo "ABCD"

}

ABCD_COUNT=26

echo "${"$(detect_value)"_COUNT}"
```

bash run.sh
run.sh: line 12: ${"$(detect_value)"_COUNT}: bad substitution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of a parameter has to be static, not produced by another expression. To do what you want, you need to use *indirect* parameter expansion, where the name of the parameter to expand is stored in *another* parameter.

```
t=$(detect_value)_COUNT
echo ${!t}
```

Depending on your use case, you might want to use an associative array instead.

```
declare -A counts

counts[ABCD]=26

detect_value () {
    echo ABCD
}

echo "${counts[$(detect_value)]}"
```

Comment: why associative array ?

Comment: Why not? (Or do you mean instead of a regular array, in which case the answer is the key needs to be a string, not an integer.)